Modifying code doesn't change the outcome in Visual Studio
I have a simple project about testing a class template, where I want to implement a general array. It has main.cpp and MyArray.hpp files.
I noticed that when I modify MyArray.hpp, e.g. add a line of cout << endl;, the output in the command prompt window when I click "Local Windows Debugger" doesn't change, it doesn't have an empty line. It looks like the code change has no effect.
The main.cpp file has the following code:
#include "MyArray.hpp"

void test01()
{
    MyArray<int> arr1(5);
}

int main()
{
    test01();

    return 0;
}

The MyArray.hpp file has the following code:
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class MyArray
{
private:
    T* pAddress;
    int m_Capacity;
    int m_Size;

public:
    MyArray(int capacity)
    {
        // cout << endl; // Adding this line doesn't change the output
        cout << "constructor with parameter" << endl;
        this->m_Capacity = capacity;
        this->m_Size = 0;
        this->pAddress = new T[this->m_Capacity];
    }
};

I tried to debug it. I created a brand new project with the same files and same code. Now modifying MyArray.hpp changes the print-out, which is weird.
I found something weird in the Build output. For the old project, the Build output after modifying MyArray.hpp is:
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: Tutorial_Template_Class, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>MyArray.hpp
1>Tutorial_Template_Class.vcxproj -> E:\Desktop\CPP_Projects\Tutorial_Template_Class\Debug\Tutorial_Template_Class.exe
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

But, for the new project, modifying MyArray.hpp does change the output, and the Build output after modifying MyArray.hpp is:
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: Tutorial_Template_Class_test, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>main.cpp
1>Tutorial_Template_Class_test.vcxproj -> E:\Desktop\CPP_Projects\Tutorial_Template_Class_test\Debug\Tutorial_Template_Class_test.exe
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

The one with unexpected behavior has MyArray.hpp in the Build output, while the normal one has main.cpp in the Build output. What is the problem here? Did I set anything wrong with Visual Studio for the project that doesn't change after I modify MyArray.hpp?

"Did I set anything wrong with Visual Studio" - clearly, you did. You should not be compiling the .hpp file directly as if it were a .cpp file. Remove that reference from your project. It should only be referencing main.cpp, which will then pull in the .hpp using the #include statement.

Thank you for your response, @RemyLebeau! What is a reference in Visual Studio?  How can I change the reference from the .hpp file to the .cpp file? I am new to Visual Studio and appreciate your help!

The new one looks correct with the build output that mentions main.cpp and nothing else. The old was wrong. MyArray.hpp should have not been listed in the sources in the top project.

Thank you for your response, @drescherjm! How should I modify the sources to make it right?

@WilliamLin at this point, I would just delete the old project file and rename the new project file to the old name.

@RemyLebeau, Lol that would work. But what is the fundamental issue here? I want to make sure if next time I set something wrong by accident I will be able to tackle it.

You can remove MyArray.hpp from the c++ sources list in Solution Explorer.
